# Sorting Ruby Arrays - failed with TypeError: can't convert Symbol into Integer

Tags: ruby

I am trying to sort an array that contains hashes. The array looks something like.

```
[:amazon, [{:price=>"  396 ", :author=>"Motwani", :name=>"Randomized Algorithms ", :url=>"", :source=>"amazon"}, 
           {:price=>"  255 ", :author=>"Thomas H. Cormen", :name=>"Introduction To Algorithms ", :url=>"", :source=>"amazon"}]]
```

I am trying to sort this array using:

```
source_array.sort_by { |p| p[1][:price] }
```

But I keep on getting error:

```
failed with TypeError: can't convert Symbol into Integer
```

Not sure what indexing is going wrong here

Comment: This is the real array which I am printing in the logs.

Comment: What is `source_array`? From your example, there are two possibilities. You need to make that clear. When you ask, you should state what your variables are. Are you trying to sort an array or a hash?

Comment: update the answer to include the exact output you want.

Comment: As @Rekin says in his answer, it's unclear why the input is a pair. Is it the result of a hash.to_a or is really this you have. No more shops, only amazon? it does not make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input is actually a pair (name, [book]), so make sure you only sort the second element of the pair (the books array):

```
[source_array[0], source_array[1].sort_by { |book| book[:price].to_i }]
```

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to sort an array of two elements:

- hash :amazon,
- inner big array.

So, any sort call on top array will try to sort these two elements.

What are you trying to achieve *could* be done this way:

```
a[1] = a[1].sort_by {|f| f[:price].to_i}
```

Edit: for a more general approach:

```
# declare source array
a  = [:amazon, 
[{:price=>"  396 ", :author=>"Motwani", :name=>"Randomized Algorithms ", :url=>"", :source=>"amazon"}, 
{:price=>"  255 ", :author=>"Thomas H. Cormen", :name=>"Introduction To Algorithms ", :url=>"", :source=>"amazon"}]]

# convert to hash for easier processing
b = Hash[*a]

# now sort former inner table by price
b.merge!(b) {|k, v|  v.sort_by {|p| p[:price].to_i}}

# return to old representation
b.to_a[0]
=> [:amazon, [{:price=>"  255 ", :author=>"Thomas H. Cormen", :name=>"Introducti
on To Algorithms ", :url=>"", :source=>"amazon"}, {:price=>"  396 ", :author=>"M
otwani", :name=>"Randomized Algorithms ", :url=>"", :source=>"amazon"}]]
```